# how to stringify an object key

Tags: javascript, json, object, key, stringify

I'm trying to reimplement JSON.stringify. I can't figure out how to turn an object like {'a': 'apple'} into {"a": "apple"}.

I've been able to stringify strings via code like

```
var a = "a";
console.log('"' + a + '"');
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
console.log(JSON.stringify(a) === '"' + a + '"'); //true
```

but this same method doesn't seem to work for object keys.

Below is my code trying to re-implement JSON.stringify

```
var stringifyJSON = function(obj) {
 if (typeof obj === "function" || typeof obj === "symbol" || typeof obj === "undefined"){
  console.log("I'm a function, symbol or undefined")
  return undefined;
 } else if (obj.toString() === "[object Object]") { //objects that aren't arrays
  console.log("I'm an object");
  var newObj = {};
  for (var key in obj) {
    var newKey = '"' + key + '"';
    if (typeof obj[key] === "function" || typeof obj[key] === "symbol" || typeof obj[key] === undefined) {
      console.log("I'm a function, symbol or undefined in an object")
      continue;
    } else if (typeof obj[key] !== "object") {
      newObj[newKey] = obj[key];
    } else {
      newObj[newKey] = stringifyJSON(obj[key]);
    }
  }
  return newObj;
 }
};

console.log(stringifyJSON({'a': 'apple'})); /*{ '"a"': 'apple' } in node, {"a": "apple"} in chrome*/
console.log(JSON.stringify({'a': 'apple'})); /*{"a":"apple"} in node and chrome*/
```

So my output actually looks correct in Chrome, but I ran my output w/ stringifyJSON and JSON.stringify through a deep equals function in Chrome and in node and it failed both times.

So how can I get double quotes to surround strings that are keys and values in objects to properly recreate JSON.stringify?

Comment: Your function should return a string, not an object.

Comment: The purpose of JSON.stringify is to create a string that represents an object. Your function is returning a new object, not a string. You've got something here to work with. The next thing I'd think about is, adding the characters '{' and '}'.

Comment: You need to call the function recursively on the value of the property, and then concatenate that into the string you're building.

Comment: "I'm trying to reimplement JSON.stringify." Why?